# После смены лицензии пропал перевод в подвале сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13354

Скопировал пока старый вариант, только номер версии поменял:

> дизайн сайта / логотип © $Year$ Stack Exchange Inc; пользовательское
>   содержимое попадает под действие лицензии $startCCLink$cc by-sa
>   4.0$closeLink$ с $startAttributionLink$указанием ссылки на источник$closeLink$.